# Why modelBuilder.Entity<SomeClass>().MapToStoredProcedures() generates only insert, update and delete stored procedures

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

i am working on a MVC project , i am using EF 6 code first approach i used

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<SomeClass>().MapToStoredProcedures()
```

to generate stored procedures and altered SPs as per my need,now the problem is i am not able to use a custom SP (with some filter) for fetching the data for index action .

every suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Because reading with stored procedures is a monolithic operation. No way to compose object graphs by combining DbSets, which is the heart of EF's LINQ support. Of course, if you want, you can use EF to read the output of stored procedures, but that's not LINQ.